# Missing Namespace in Doctrine Generated Entities?

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm generating entities using doctrine 2 from the command line but my application requires a namespace to be set, how can I make sure that the created entities will have **namespace Entities;** at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Create next file structure:

```
application/
    /models/
        /Entities/
            User.php
```

and User.php model has next namespace:

```
namespace Entities;

class User { ... }

$user = new \Entities\User();
```

dont forget to set

```
$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver('/path/to/app/application/models/Entities');
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
```

Comment: I have exactly the file structure that you suggest, I failed to mention that my entities files are created by using yalm files, If I was creating the class entities manually I guess I could add the missing line for the namespace, I guess I'm still lost with this doctrine thing...